Arduino R3 trouble connecting to ESP8266 - Timed Out Error
I am attempting to turn my generic Arduino R3 (an ELEGOO UNO R3) into an IoT device by connecting an ESP8266 ESP-01 WiFi module.
Here are my wiring connection:
GND - GND
TXD - RX
IO2 - 3.3v (through board)
EN - GND (through board)
IOD - GND (through board)
RXD - TX
VCC - 3.3v
When uploading the code I keep getting the error:
'A fatal esptool.py error occurred: Failed to connect to ESP8266: Timed out waiting for packet header'
Here is the code:
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>

const char* ssid = "";
const char* password = "";

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  delay(10);

  // Connect to Wi-Fi
  Serial.println();
  Serial.print("Connecting to ");
  Serial.println(ssid);

  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);

  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
  }

  Serial.println("");
  Serial.println("WiFi connected");
  Serial.println("IP address: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
}

void loop() {
  // Nothing to do here
}

what do i do?

a Blink or empty sketch uploads successful? for upload wire RX to RX and TX to TX

This code is for using the ESP-01 as a stand-alone Arduino, not for using it as a WiFi modem attached to a Uno. If you want to use it as a stand-alone Arduino as your code shown, you need to put the ESP-01 into programming mode by holding the IO0 to GND and short the RST to GND briefly... To use the ESP-01 as a modem attached to an Uno, you can read this answer for more information.
